# Text field using OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, text, lwjgl, slick2d

So, I'm new to OpenGL and trying to create a 2D Multiplayer game, I know how to do all of the networking, although the graphics portion is honestly kicking my buttox.

I have tried looking at NiftyGUI aswell as TWL as they have been recommended a-lot, although I can't seem to get a grasp of them as there aren't very many tutorials and no videos to help explain what's going on, not to mention the OpenGL Documentary page is just horribly laid out.

I've attemped drawing a black rectangle, which I was going to go ahead and outline in white somehow and making that a temporary textbox, by drawing white font onto it, although I don't even know how to draw font. These are just a few of the things I'm strugling with that I can't find and I'm aware that I'm going to have to use some libraries, so I'll name the ones I have implemented currently.

- LWJGL
- Slick2D

I don't have any others currently, besides for TWL but I can't figure out how to use it for the life of me.

Here's the code that I made myself while trying to get a small black rectangle going

```
void drawTextBox(int fromLeft, int fromTop, int width, int height) {
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(fromLeft, fromTop);  // Upper Left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); 
        glVertex2i(fromLeft - width, fromTop);  // Uppright
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); 
        glVertex2i(fromLeft - width, fromTop + height);  // Bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); 
        glVertex2i(fromLeft, fromTop + height); // bottom left
    glEnd();
}
```

This is working correctly, all but one part... It's drawing the last texture that I have loaded, even though I'm not binding it anywhere in the program, because I've made sure of it. Then it's scaling it to fit into the dimensions of the text-box.

Could someone help me resolve this error and direct me to where I can learn how to set the opacity of quads as-well as draw some text?

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have a "Documentary" page. What exactly were you talking about?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the texture you want right before calling the function. Without knowing how you've "made sure" that the other texture is not being bound, that's all I can say. Also, for changing opacity simply use one of `GL11.glColor4_` functions; the last parameter is the alpha (opacity) of the color.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know about glColor4, also... I don't want a texture bound to this, I just want it to be Black.

Comment: Then don't call `glTexCoord2f`. That function is used to render a texture over the quad.

Comment: Not a problem :)
Don't forget to accept if it solved your question.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Please don't spread misinformation. glTexCoord2f just setes the texture coordinate used by the next vertex. It neither draws a texture, nor does it enable it.

Comment: @ChristianTucker: ValekHalfHeart gave you wrong information. To disable using a texture either `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` or `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);' right before your rectangle drawing,

Answer (score 0):

```
void drawTextBox(int fromLeft, int fromTop, int width, int height) {

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, <B>0.5f</B>);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(fromLeft, fromTop);  // Upper Left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); 
        glVertex2i(fromLeft - width, fromTop);  // Uppright
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); 
        glVertex2i(fromLeft - width, fromTop + height);  // Bottom right
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); 
        glVertex2i(fromLeft, fromTop + height); // bottom left
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

This block of code allows you to draw a white rectangle with %50 opacity.

Take a look at the **BOLDED** part (0.5f). This float number defines the opacity of your rectangle. The bigger this number is (0.0f~1.0f), the more the opacity of the rectangle is.